# Nuget command line behind a closed network, the remote name could be resolved, packages.nuget.org

Tags: nuget

I am trying to use Nuget Command line util to Pack a nuspec file.
When i call "Pack" I get an unhanded exception,
"The remote name could not be resolved packages.nuget.org

I am within a network that is not connected to the internet.

Is there a way to overcome this issue?

Thanks

Tal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's strange, as the 'pack' command does not need to access the internet.

But there is one possible explanation: if you got nuget.exe from http://nuget.codeplex.com/releases/view/58939, then it is actually just a bootstrapper that downloads the real nuget.exe on first run (and it needs internet access for that).

Comment: This doesn't explain the issue I'm seeing in the same situation - every nuget feature works except for package restore - at which point the OP's error message appears. I've disabled the default package repository because it's not accessible from  our network; we have a local one.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem since my development computer is not connected to the Internet. I downloaded the complete nuget.exe (offline version) and it solved the issue.

You can get the "offline version" of nuget.exe from here: https://nuget.org/nuget.exe